# RegEx for passing 5.0 and failing 5.1

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have been searching for a while , my requirement is I want to accept only integers and if user enters 5.00 that also I want to accept but I do not want to accept 5.01

I have seen regex to accept only integers but that does not meet my requirement completely.

REGEX to ACCEPT:

```
5.0,
7.0,
9.00,
77
```

REGEX to DECLINE:

```
5.1,
55.45
```

Comment: Did you try to write a regex yourself ? What was the problem ? Such a regex is trivial and is just a way to write down your requirement. Searching for an existing one isn't usually a good solution.

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what you are trying to do? Sometimes regexes are not the best solution, and I feel it's the case here as you seem to be dealing with numeric values. Something like `value % 1 === 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will match your stated requirements:

```
^\d+(?:\.00?)?$
```

It matches any number, optionally followed by `.0` or `.00`.